# bootstrap modal how to load http file inside

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

is there any way to load http:// located file into modal windows?

somenthing like :

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-large" data-toggle="modal" href="#http://localhost/login.html"> <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Login </a>
```

obviously i can do it with a separated js method (like jquery load()) but i would like to know if is there any possibility to do that without implementing any new js.

Comment: What I usually do is to load the URL with Ajax and then replace the modal body contents with the response, using .html(). Not a very convenient workaround in many cases, so I'd like to hear any other suggestions too.

Comment: @periklis yep man that is what i used to do, me too waiting for a good alternative (bootstrap self alternative should be great!!) as for example fancybox jquery plugin is so good for loading everything inside modals (iframes,files,html etc), this feature should be implemented on bootstrap-modals i think :P

Comment: See comments in https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/936

Answer (score 0):

Make an `iFrame` with an ID and load your `login.html` into that. Give the iFrame's ID to that modal like `href="#iFrameId"`. This iFrame should be in the same HTML file that your anchor is.

Comment: i think iframe is the worst solution :P

Comment: @Badaboooooom You want to load *another page* inside *your page*. That is the job for iframes, no matter how you put it.

Comment: @Christian nope, i'm wondering if i can load page content not an iframe, usually i use jquery load() so ..again ... wondering if bootstrap allows load() natively

Comment: @Badaboooooom That's not how you put it in your question. `Page Content != Any Kind of URL`

Comment: @Christian are you kidding? check my question i sad "jquery load" and obviously you can get html content by urls, i think you are the only one didn't understood my question so sorry for my english if so!